Negative Binominal Regression vs Ordinary Logistic Regression
I have social media data from an election period with thousands of political actors' posts on social media. The dataset has many control variables such as date, follower number, presence of visuals, whether it is a retweet of a popular actor etc.
The study is essentially about linguistics. My goal is to test whether metaphor-related metrics are associated with high engagement (likes, shares, comments). Since it is social media data, there is high overdispersion. I confirmed that negative binominal regression is the best option.
After fitting the model with like count, I noticed that the model is struggling with the posts that have very high engagement or very low engagement. It also seems to have significant outliers.




Considering this is social media data from a highly intense period, I am not surprised that the model is struggling with certain posts. Most of the underpredicted posts include either special/sensational visuals, videos or announcements that make them very high.
Since they are not false data and inherent in social media, I did not remove them. Main goal is not having a model that predicts engagement but to see if the metaphor metrics are positively correlated with engagement.
I am wondering if this is normal due to the nature of data. Also, if NBR is the correct test for me or should I consider OLR after factoring engagement data based on percentiles as high, medium and low engagement.

You need to find the equivalent of a Q-Q plot in ordinary linear models to check distributional assumptions of the NB model.

There are a wide variety of count models that extend beyond Poisson and NB2 models like yours which could be better. It could be that your data is more skewed than expected (for which a PIG model may be better), there are a lot of zeroes (where zero-inflated or hurdle models are more appropriate) or there are special variance properties at play (if it is something highly specific, a customized GAMLSS model could also be better). Are there any hidden group variables you are missing? There seems to be a big split in your indexed values.

Thank you very much for your comment @ShawnHemelstrand
PIG and GAMLSS suggestions were very useful.
